# Rails: How to show link with www.example.com but not show with <a> tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using auto_link gem when a user write `www.google.com` the view generate a link. But also if user write `<a href="www.google.com">` the view generate a link.

Simply, I want that `<a>` tag doesn't generate link, but only `www.example.com`. (like Facebook, twitter etc..., if you write `<a>` tag doesn't generate a link.

Is possibile to generate link only with `www.example.com` method? And if user write `<a href="www.google.com">` generate a simply string `<a href="www.google.com">` and not a link.

Comment: Have you looked into the [rinku](https://github.com/vmg/rinku) gem? It's aimed to be a drop-in replacement for `auto_link` and appears to support a `skip_tags` option to prevent double-linking.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to HTML escape the string first before passing it to the method that generates the links.

Something like this might work for you:

```
<%= auto_link(html_escape(user_generated_content)) %>
```

Or shorter:

```
<%= auto_link(h(user_generated_content)) %>
```